# Accessing values after enumerate when iterating through a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have code that iterates through a large dataframe using df.itertuples()
I understand this is slow, and can be much faster if I convert to a dict and use df.to_dict('records)

The problem I am having is simply how to access those values.
I need to use enumerate (because I need the index value).
With itertuples, it is simple (to me) to access values with i.index or i.column_1
How do I do this in a dict after enumerate?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'column_1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'column_2':[5,10,15,20,25], 'column_3':[3,6,9,12,15], 'column_4':[8,7,6,5,4]})
display(df)

### original code using itertuples
for i in df.itertuples():
  if i.Index % 2 == 0:
    print('column_1 value using itertuples',i.column_1)
  else:
    print('skip this row using itertuples')

### trying as dict
df_dict = df.to_dict('records')
for row in df_dict:
  for index, (key,value) in enumerate(row.items()):
    if index % 2 == 0:
      print('column_1 value',row['column_1']) ### this does not work
    else:
      print('skip this row')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is not necessary, you just want:

```
>>> for i, row in enumerate(df.to_dict('records')):
...     if i % 2 == 0:
...         print('column_1 value',row['column_1'])
...
column_1 value 1
column_1 value 3
column_1 value 5
```

Although note, this won't give you the actual index in your data frame, `enumerate` just gives you an increasing counter (it *enumerates* the items in the iterable)